# Percona state transfer failed

Tags: mysql, database-replication, percona

I am trying to start a `Percona` cluster for `MySQL`. The bootstrap node has been successfully started. However, while trying to add a new node, I am having issues.

Reading through the log files, the nodes have successfully exchanged the state UUIDs, but eventually the following error occurs,

```
[Warning] WSREP: Failed to prepare for incremental state transfer: Local state UUID (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) does not match group state UUID (9752b8e9-433c-11e5-8793-1e7ab54f8c84): 1 (Operation not permitted)
     at galera/src/replicator_str.cpp:prepare_for_IST():463. IST will be unavailable.
```

And with this the state transfer fails.

Please help me understand what is failing in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Since IST is unavailable, it should have attempted an SST. Do you see that later in the logs? You may have a missing MySQL user account or blocked firewall ports.

Comment: I will look into that! Where should be the user available, on the new joining node or the bootstrap node? I am currently unable to add any users to the new node because the `mysql` service is unable to start.

Comment: The SST user must be defined on the donor node with @localhost permissions. 

`mysql> CREATE USER 'sstuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 's3cret';
mysql> GRANT RELOAD, LOCK TABLES, REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO 'sstuser'@'localhost';`